# How to wait for user prompt when calling a job

Tags: jenkins

here is my problem : I use jenkins v1.613, my job A is parameterized ( choice) of countries and I have a job B parameterized (List subversion tags) where the repository URL is like http://my-svn.com/xxx/{$country}/tags.

I create a multijob for "chaining" job A and B but after calling the job A, I'm waiting from jenkins to open me a new window with prompt on job B in order to select a tags from http://my-svn.com/xxx/spain/tags....no way

please help, any clues ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible if you use the [Workflow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin).

It's probably much more effort to set up than the answer from Slav, but workflow makes a lot of complicated setups possible.
In a workflow, you can define an [`input` step](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/c15589f/TUTORIAL.md#pausing-flyweight-vs-heavyweight-executors), which will pause and wait for user input.

This can prompt with a given `message` and a list of `parameters`, which function in the same way as a regular parameterised build.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906998/how-do-we-access-jenkins-workflow-input-parameter-values) for an example, or check out the documentation and [workflow snippet generator](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/c15589f/TUTORIAL.md#exploring-available-steps).

Answer (score 0):

Not going to happen, the way you described it. Jenkins is meant to be run automatically. It can take any number of parameters upfront before triggering the job, but it won't stop and prompt/wait for user once it is running.

You need to select the `country` **and** `tags` on the first screen (Job A) and then pass the `tags` value to the downstream job.

Consider **[Dynamic Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin)** plugin to achieve this in the same page. They have detailed instructions on the wiki.

Comment: thanks, but how can  I get **tags**  depending on **country** on the same view ?

Comment: Read over the "Dynamic Extended Choice parameter" plugin. Updated to answer